# Finding general solution to $x^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 6x \frac{dy}{dx} +12y = x^2 + 6x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that the differential equation below has solutions of the form: $y = Ax^r$

$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + ax \frac{dy}{dx} +by = 0,$

where r is a constant.

Hence find the general solution of the ode:

$x^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 6x \frac{dy}{dx} +12y = x^2 + 6x$

**My attempt:**

Lets differentiate y with respect to x:

$y = Ax^r$

$y' = Arx^{r-1}$

$y'' = Ar(r-1)x^{r-2}$

Then I substituted this in the ode giving:

$x^2 (Ar(r-1)x^{r-2}) - 6x(Arx^{r-1}) + 12(Ax^r) = x^2 + 6x$

which simplifies to:

$x^r(Ar(r-1) - 6Ar + 2A) = x(x+6)$

However this never seems to be correct? since we require two different power of x on the LHS whilst this is not possible?

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is it the second derivative of y with respect to x??

Comment: yes it should be, why is it incorrect?

Comment: There is a typo

Comment: @user2250537 Rohan is referring to your typo in the first line $d^2 x/dx^2 \ldots$

Comment: Yes sorry fixed it :')

Comment: @user2250537 : the method you are applying is valuable for the homogeneous ODE : $x^2y''-6xy'+12y=0$ . Solve it for $r$. So, you obtain the general solution of the homogeneous ODE. Then, you have to find a particular solution for the complete ODE and adding it.

Comment: You are told that the equation has solution**s** of the form $y=Ax^r$. There are two of them $y=Ax^r+Bx^s$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will first find a general solution for 
$$x^2y\prime\prime-6xy\prime+12y=0 $$ Our trial solution is $y=Ax^r$. Substituting it in the equation we get the following quadratic on $r$;$$r^2-7r+12=0\Rightarrow r=3 , 4$$So general solution is for above D.E. is $y=Ax^3+Bx^4$

Now notice a particular solution for;$$x^2y\prime\prime-6xy\prime+12y=x^2+6x$$
 is $y=\frac{x^2}{2}+x$. So, the general solution for the original DE is $y=\frac{x^2}{2}+x+Ax^3+Bx^4$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Euler-Cauchy equation

assume $z=\log x$ to get
$$y''(z)-7y'(z)+12y(z)=e^{2z}+6e^z$$ 
then solve the new D.E